# Error when trying to run app on localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs

I wrote this app using `create-react-app` a year ago. Now when I try to run it using `npm start` I get the following error:

> Home(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

I've updated all the dependencies. `react`, `react-dom`, `react-router-dom` and `react-scripts`

The code in error seems to be:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Router />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Can you provide your full code? What's the full call to `ReactDOM.render` and what's the contents of `Home`?

Comment: Post your `Router ` component.

Comment: Check the render method of your `Home` component. It seems to not return anything.

Comment: Here is the full code to ReactDom.render..  import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Router from './router';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';



ReactDOM.render(<Router />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();

Comment: And the code for home is.... import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import './css/home.css';

const Home = () => {
  <div className="home">
    <div className="clip1" />
    <NavLink to="/gallery" activeStyle={{ color: '#f78b10' }}>
      <h1>Norbert Karrass</h1>
    </NavLink>
  </div>;
};
export default Home;

Answer (score 0):

**You are not returning the JSX from the Home Component**

Fix:

```
const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div className="home">
            <div className="clip1" />
            <NavLink to="/gallery" activeStyle={{ color: '#f78b10' }}>
                <h1>Norbert Karrass</h1>
            </NavLink>
        </div>;
  )
};
```

Or a more fancy way:

```
 const Home = () => (
    <div className="home">
        <div className="clip1" />
        <NavLink to="/gallery" activeStyle={{ color: '#f78b10' }}>
            <h1>Norbert Karrass</h1>
        </NavLink>
    </div>;
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Fernando. It's strange as I haven't touched this code in over a year and at that time it worked fine. Now it works great :)